# To what namespace does the expression `that namespace` highlighted below refers to, in [namespace.def]/2 in the current C++ draft?

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, declaration

[[namespace.def]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.namespace#namespace.def.general-2):

In a *named-namespace-definition*, the *identifier* is the name of the namespace. If the *identifier*, when looked up, refers to a *namespace-name* (but not a *namespace-alias*) that was introduced in the namespace in which the *named-namespace-definition* appears or that was introduced in a member of the inline namespace set of **that namespace**, the *namespace-definition* *extends* the previously-declared namespace. Otherwise, the *identifier* is introduced as a *namespace-name* into the declarative region in which the *named-namespace-definition* appears.

Comment: It refers to "the namespace in which the named-namespace-definition appears".

Comment: ...that was introduced in the **namespace** in which lalalala or that was introduced in a lalala of **that namespace**

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm not so sure about this. It could also be the namespace that was previously declared and which is being extended by the namespace being defined.

Comment: You can be sure. It's not some sort of reference to an intricate normative definition. It really is as molbdnilo says. The phrasing is a bit verbose, but ultimately, that's the namespace being referred to here.

Answer (score 3):

To make it clear consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    inline namespace B
    {
        namespace C
        {
            int x = 10;
        }
    }
    
    namespace C
    {
        int y = 2 * x;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "A::C::x = " << A::C::x << '\n';
    std::cout << "A::C::y = " << A::C::y << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
A::C::x = 10
A::C::y = 20
```

In the named-namespace-definition of the namespace C, the identifier is the name of the namespace.

If the identifier `C`, when looked up, refers to a namespace-name (but not a namespace-alias) that was introduced in the namespace A in which the named-namespace-definition appears **or that was introduced in the member B of the inline namespace set of that namespace A**, the (**second**) namespace-definition of the namespace C extends the previously-declared namespace C.

Comment: I still have one point that is not clear to me. The text says "If the identifier when looked up refers to a namespace-name ...". But in your code there is no lookup for the name `C` that would find the `namespace A::B::C`. All the lookups would find just `A::C`.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso When a namespace identifier is looked up in a namespace also the set of inline namespaces of that namespace are considered.

Comment: Well, again there is no lookup in your code that passes trough the inline namespace B either..

Comment: @JoãoAfonsoWhen the namespace C is searched in the namespace A also the set of inline namespaces is searched. So the second definition of the namespace C extends the definition of the namespace C declared in the inline namespace B.

Comment: AFAICT the standard doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso At least the quote you provided says about this. Also see the qualified name lookup.